# Web design software for non-designers

Tags: html, wysiwyg

I'm a system programming geek. My drawing and design skills are very limited and I barely know how to use Photoshop.

Currently, web development software only offers separate options for coders (non-visual) and designers (visual). But I'm trying to find a WYSIWYG (visual) website design piece of software optimized for engineers, rather than artists.

Something like drag & drop building blocks, select various layouts, options. Add graphics.

Don't get me wrong - it must not be a primitive template-based editor - I'm looking for advanced solution, so I can make a professional website.

Comment: if you want to make a website like you said I would not call it professional. Try with MS Publisher, FrontPage, Word... Publisher and Word save as html, not the cleanest HTML at all but there you do have WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you will find a "golden bullet" here.

That being said I consider myself in a similar vein. I'm a pretty competent front end developer with minimal design skills. Although kind of template based, [Artisteer](http://www.artisteer.com/) is worth a look. I use it to get me started then I tweak from there. Being an ASP.net guy Visual Studio is my normal poison for tweaking. [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) is a free version. Though Dreamweaver etc would also work.

If you are getting serious about this, you make sure you have the basics of HTML and CSS covered so you know what you are doing when you are tweaking templates.

Comment: Thank you for the Artisteer! It's awesome.

Answer (score 1):

you best option is what most of us nerds do and thats hire a designer, or go to something like template monster  thing is with design, it is a creative mind... when it comes to programming it is logical mind.  Fair enough there are a few good designers out there that can make a website, code etc   but to what level.    I just right code, its what i am good at, my pal brian creates designes for me.... because thats what he is good at.

:-)

Comment: just as an extra note, jquery UI  is quite slick for stuff like notices, errors and other  items to jazz up an interface without knowing design.   you can roll your own style on there website.